# Why I can't login to the console after I changed the admin url of magento

Tags: magento

http://172.26.26.37/yecun/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/d7237fb46f4d3336e79a9392d9096582/?SID=e5cpqqlh0i8ml6p6a7hvg3d517

I change the default 'admin' to 'yecun' in the admin url setting in system=>configure ... and then I forever can't login anymore!
I can only get the above redirected url and 404 page.

magento is bitch!

Answer (score 0):

You can try clear var/cache folder and login admin using firefox or safari browsers.